# What should "git rev-list origin..HEAD" return?

Tags: git, git-rev-list

The [git-rev-list man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list) shows the following commands:

```
$ git rev-list origin..HEAD
$ git rev-list HEAD ^origin
```

However, when I run the 1st command, I get the following error:

```
$ git rev-list origin..HEAD fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin..HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree. Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this: 'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

'origin' refers to the following remote:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  c:/hands_on/git/learn/clone/../repo_1 (fetch)
origin  c:/hands_on/git/learn/clone/../repo_1 (push)
```

Am I using the command incorrectly? Also, I thought the rev-list command takes commits as input, so I'm not clear why the man page uses 'origin' which is a remote rather. What have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

git-rev-parse(1) explains how the name of a remote can be used as a ref:

```
<refname>, e.g. master, heads/master, refs/heads/master
   A symbolic ref name. E.g.  master typically means the commit object
   referenced by refs/heads/master. If you happen to have both heads/master and
   tags/master, you can explicitly say heads/master to tell Git which one you
   mean. When ambiguous, a <refname> is disambiguated by taking the first match
   in the following rules:

    1. If $GIT_DIR/<refname> exists, that is what you mean (this is usually
    useful only for HEAD, FETCH_HEAD, ORIG_HEAD, MERGE_HEAD and
    CHERRY_PICK_HEAD);

    2. otherwise, refs/<refname> if it exists;

    3. otherwise, refs/tags/<refname> if it exists;

    4. otherwise, refs/heads/<refname> if it exists;

    5. otherwise, refs/remotes/<refname> if it exists;

    6. otherwise, refs/remotes/<refname>/HEAD if it exists.
```

And git-remote(1) explains what `refs/remotes/<remote>/HEAD` is in the description of `git remote set-head`:

```
   set-head
       Sets or deletes the default branch (i.e. the target of the symbolic-ref
       refs/remotes/<name>/HEAD) for the named remote. Having a default branch
       for a remote is not required, but allows the name of the remote to be
       specified in lieu of a specific branch. For example, if the default
       branch for origin is set to master, then origin may be specified wherever
       you would normally specify origin/master.
```

In other words, it uses the default branch for the remote, and you don’t appear to have one.

Comment: After establishing the default branch for the remote, it works:

    $ git remote set-head origin master
    $ git rev-list origin..HEAD
f8def1b0a13f8a2d83b6f538416358979e86a890

Comment: @Ltf4an after trying to set default branch I get error: Not a valid ref: refs/remotes/origin/master. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

As you correctly said, `git rev-list` is supposed to take a commit range there, so using the name of a remote does not really make sense.

The documentation previously (pre 2006, so very long ago) said the following:

> A special notation `<commit1>..<commit2>` can be used as a
>   short-hand for `^<commit1> <commit2>`.

This was then changed with [this commit](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8c02eee29e116355474250a5e9270db6034c60de) ([mailing list discussion](http://www.gelato.unsw.edu.au/archives/git/0609/26600.html)) to:

> A special notation `"'<commit1>'..'<commit2>'"` can be used as a short-hand for `"^'<commit1>' '<commit2>'"`. For example, either of the following may be used interchangeably:
>
> ```
> $ git-rev-list origin..HEAD
> $ git-rev-list HEAD ^origin
> ```

The commit message for that change was the following:

> git-rev-list(1): group options; reformat; document more options

I can only assume, that the use of `origin` there was a mistake and not meant to literally refer to a remote. The documentation is plastered with inconsistent examples (`rev-list` alone uses foo/bar/baz, origin/HEAD, and A/B), so I wouldn’t put too much weight on that.

The important part though is, that the command is supposed to work with branches (or any *ref* in general), and remotes are not valid refs on their own.

Comment: @minitech A remote *branch*, sure, but not a remote. Even if if took the default upstream branch (something which you cannot define on a remote-level, but only in the context of local branches—which is not available with `rev-list`), it doesn’t make much sense. Are you sure you don’t have a ref (branch/tag/something) called `origin` somewhere in your repository? What does `git rev-parse origin` show?

Comment: No, *a remote*. See git-rev-parse(1): “6. otherwise, refs/remotes/<refname>/HEAD if it exists.”

Comment: That’s really weird. I can’t reproduce that at all…